# ASRock Z590M Pro4 Failed to install ubuntu

Tags: 18.04, system-installation, intel, bios, usb-installation

I have a problem installing Ubuntu 18.05. I am using an ASRock Z590M Pro4 motherboard and an i9 11900F Processor. Which sediments do I need to use in BIOS? When I start the installation, the computer turns itself off.

Comment: You weren't specific as to what Ubuntu (server? desktop? you've tagged 18.04 but also called it 18.05). Ubuntu 18.04 LTS was the 2018-April (thus 18.04) release of Ubuntu.  Which 18.04 ISO were you using? ie. was it a updated ISO with newer stack? or the 2018-April stack?  Did you validate your ISO? validate your write to installation media?  ie. please provide details.

Comment: For a i9 11900F you need the newest kernel you can get. Installing a release 3 years older than the hardware is always a very bad idea.

Comment: Desktop »Product Information
Model Name: Z590M Pro4
BIOS Version: P1,90
»Configuration
CPU: i9-11900F(B0) 
Memory: Kingston FURY Beast - DDR4 - kit - 64 GB: 2 x 32 G
Video  Card: Asus Dual RTX 2070-O8G-MINI,PCIe 
HDD: Samsung 970EVO Plus,M.2 
OS: Ubuntu 18,04,5

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that. The same problem is with the latest version of Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS